# Filter By Last 14 Days Pivot Table Excel 2010

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table on a worksheet that contains a Date column. I have created a Pivot Table/Chart on a new worksheet. I want to be able to filter the data in the chart being displayed by the last 14 days (Always relative to the current date).

I have the same problem as this user:[filtering an Excel pivot table to show the last 24 hours data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320158/filtering-an-excel-pivot-table-to-show-the-last-24-hours-data)

Except I can't add a column to the source Data and I need it within 14 days instead of 24 hours. There must be built-in way to do this or can I do this in VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by date, of course, but without VBA I think it has to be manual. Here's a VBA routine that sets it to the last 14 days, including today:

```
Sub FilterPivotByDate()
Dim pvt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim DaysToShow As Long
Dim DateString As String

Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
DaysToShow = 114
DateString = Format(Date - (DaysToShow - 1), "m/d/yyyy")
With pvt.PivotFields("date")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlAfterOrEqualTo, Value1:=DateString
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the chance to write fun code.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can help me with this but it cropped up afterwards. In order to use your solution, I need to add the Date as an Axis (Category) - Is there a way to do the same thing if it were a report filter instead? The problem is that it's dividing my results by month

Comment: Is a report filter your first choice, or do want to do it because it will solve your month grouping issue? To do it in a report filter I think the only way is to loop through each item and set its `Visible` property. I don't have any more time now, but will check back later.

Comment: I don't need to filter the dates in any way other than the past 14 days, although my design changed - so the dates don't always need to be relative to the current date. I added 2 calendar controls to get those between dates. So I need to reference that Axis(Category) of my Date field to filter between dates, but not have it apply it's default filtering functionality where it's splitting up my values by month.

Comment: I can make dates in a pivot table act like what you're seeing as the default by choosing month in the Group dialog. Conversely, right-clicking the dates and choosing UnGroup makes both the pivot table and pivot chart show each date separately.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. It turned out I just needed to group by seconds to avoid it breaking up my results by month.